# React component is not loading with latest state returned by multiple independent async-await requests

Tags: typescript, async-await, react-hooks, promise, use-effect

I'm creating a travel related form using React-typeScript. The first component

> TravelForm

uses multiple async-await request within useEffect hook for updating state of the second component

> TravelGuideFields

However, my second component TravelGuideFields is not at all showing the updated values of the props. I checked with React dev tool, the state is correctly updated with new value. I feel my component is loading with the new values. It probably I'm doing multiple async-await call and therefore the component is loading with final result value. Is there any otherway so that my components get updated with new values ?

So, here is my first component where I'm doing the multiple network call within effect hook,

```
import { FC, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
    getOrderedbooks,
    getOrderedSportsGears,
    getOrderedTravelMaps
} from "../../httpRequests/TravelRequests";

import TravelGuideFields from "./TravelGuideFields";

const TravelForm: FC = () => {
    //states
    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState<TravelInputInterface>({
        bookName: "",
        bookPrice: 0.0,
        runningShoeBrand: "",
        runningShoeCost: 0.0,
        mapType: "",
        mapCost: 0.0,
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        const resultInputs: TravelInputInterface = {
             bookName: "",
             bookPrice: 0.0,
             runningShoeBrand: "",
             runningShoeCost: 0.0,
             mapType: "",
             mapCost: 0.0,
        };
        const fetchBooks = async () => {
            const res = await getOrderedbooks();
        

            if (res !== undefined) {
                resultInputs.bookName = res.BOOK_NAME;
                resultInputs.bookPrice = res.BOOK_PRICE;
          
            }
        };
        fetchBooks();

        const fetchSportsGear = async () => {
            const res = await getOrderedSportsGears();
        

            if (res !== undefined) {
                resultInputs.runningShoeBrand = res.SHOE_BRAND;
                resultInputs.bookPrice = res.SHOE_PRICE;
          
            }
        };
        fetchSportsGear();

        const fetchTravelMaps = async () => {
            const res = await getOrderedTravelMaps();
            
            if (res !== undefined) {
                resultInputs.mapType = res.MAP_TYPE;
                resultInputs.mapCost = res.MAP_COST;
       
            }
        };

        fetchTravelMaps();
        console.log({ resultInputs });
        setInputs(resultInputs);
    }, []);

    
    return <TravelGuideFormFields inputs={inputs} />;
};
default BlockchainConstantsForm;
```

**//TravelGuideFields component**

```
const TravelGuideFields: FC<any> = ({inputs}) => {

return (
<div>
<div class="books"><input value={inputs.bookName} disabled/>
<input value={inputs.bookPrice} disabled/></div>
<div class="maps"><input value={inputs.mapType} disabled/></div>
<div class="sports"><input value={inputs.runningShoe} disabled/></div>
</div>
)
}

export default TravelGuideFields

//TravelRequests (HTTP request generator file)

//Books
export const getOrderedbooks = async (): Promise<bookInterface | undefined> => {
    const res = await get(
         `${mainURL}/books`
     );
    
    if (res.status === 200) {
        
        return res.data;
    }

    return undefined;
};
```

//SportsGear

```
export const getOrderedSportsGears = async (): Promise<sportsInterface | undefined> => {
        const res = await get(
             `${mainURL}/sports`
         );
        
        if (res.status === 200) {
            
            return res.data;
        }
    
        return undefined;
    };

//Travelmaps

    export const getOrderedTravelMaps = async (): Promise<mapInterface | undefined> => {
            const res = await get(
                 `${mainURL}/map`
             );
            
            if (res.status === 200) {
                
                return res.data;
            }
        
            return undefined;
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is where the problem is.

You are not doing `async-await` at all level of your code.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const resultInputs: TravelInputInterface = {
             bookName: "",
             bookPrice: 0.0,
             runningShoeBrand: "",
             runningShoeCost: 0.0,
             mapType: "",
             mapCost: 0.0,
        };
        const fetchBooks = async () => {
            const res = await getOrderedbooks();
        

            if (res !== undefined) {
                resultInputs.bookName = res.BOOK_NAME;
                resultInputs.bookPrice = res.BOOK_PRICE;
          
            }
        };
        fetchBooks();

        const fetchSportsGear = async () => {
            const res = await getOrderedSportsGears();
        

            if (res !== undefined) {
                resultInputs.runningShoeBrand = res.SHOE_BRAND;
                resultInputs.bookPrice = res.SHOE_PRICE;
          
            }
        };
        fetchSportsGear();

        const fetchTravelMaps = async () => {
            const res = await getOrderedTravelMaps();
            
            if (res !== undefined) {
                resultInputs.mapType = res.MAP_TYPE;
                resultInputs.mapCost = res.MAP_COST;
       
            }
        };

        fetchTravelMaps();
        console.log({ resultInputs });
        setInputs(resultInputs);
    }, []);
```

This code above is where the problem lies.

You can fix this by changing some code into:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const promises = [getOrderedbooks, getOrderedSportsGears, getOrderedTravelMaps];

        Promise.all(promises).then(promises => {
            const [booksResponse, sportsGearResponse, travelMapsResponse] = promises;

            const resultInputs: TravelInputInterface = {
                bookName: "",
                bookPrice: 0.0,
                runningShoeBrand: "",
                runningShoeCost: 0.0,
                mapType: "",
                mapCost: 0.0,
           };

            if (booksResponse !== undefined){
                resultInputs.bookName = booksResponse.BOOK_NAME;
                resultInputs.bookPrice = booksResponse.BOOK_PRICE;
            }

            if (sportsGearResponse !== undefined){
                resultInputs.runningShoeBrand = sportsGearResponse.SHOE_BRAND;
                resultInputs.bookPrice = sportsGearResponse.SHOE_PRICE;
            }

            if (travelMapsResponse !== undefined) {
                resultInputs.mapType = travelMapsResponse.MAP_TYPE;
                resultInputs.mapCost = travelMapsResponse.MAP_COST;
            }

            setInputs(resultInputs);
        })        
    }, []);
```

Doing it with `Promise.all` will guarantee you the logic will only run once all API are completed.
And since `useEffect` can't be an async function, using `.then` will be much cleaner than trying to use `async-await` keywords.

You can still use `async-await` tho if you want, by wrapping the whole `useEffect` with another async function and calling it inside of the `useEffect`.

Comment: Hi @michael thanks for trying to help me. I tried it. const [booksResponse, sportsGearResponse, travelMapsResponse] = promises;  the promises here returns array of three async functions. LIke this, {promises: Array(3)}promises: (3) [ƒ, ƒ, ƒ][[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: Ah, if you still receive promises, you can call `.then()` function to receive the value. Not sure tho why did you get promises instead.

Comment: @MichaelHarley The point is they're *not* getting promises. Your code puts functions in the array that should contain `promises`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use promise.all() with await you didn't add await that's why it gives you a promise
try this and let me know if its working or not.

```
const [booksResponse, sportsGearResponse , travelMapsResponse] = await 
Promise.all([
getOrderedbooks(),
getOrderedSportsGears(),
getOrderedTravelMaps(),
]);
```